# Solana Anchor How to test different Signers interacting with program functions

Tags: solana

How can I test in Solana Anchor if a hacker can call or invoke certain program functions?

Is it by changing the first element inside the signers array:

```
await program.rpc.initializeProgram(
 arg1, arg2, ... {
 accounts: {...}
 signers: [keypair1, keypair2, ... keypairN],
)
```

But in some tutorial cases, this signers array are omitted...
Where in Anchor can I set the caller's keypair that is used to sign the transaction?

See example Anchor codes from https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/tutorials/tutorial-1

keywords: smart contract, security test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your anchor tests, it will use the provider.wallet as the payer and thus automatically use the provider.wallet as the signer.

You can also add signers to your javascript calls through the signers array field incase your program requires them to be signers.

Tutorial 1 is not a realistic example here, since anyone can come in and modify the accounts.

By default the anchor tests use the provider.wallet as the payer and signer for transactions. If you want to use another wallet, you would have to create another anchor program instance, follow the function below.

```
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { provider, program } from '../config';

export function programPaidBy(payer: anchor.web3.Keypair): anchor.Program {
  const newProvider = new anchor.Provider(provider.connection, new anchor.Wallet(payer), {});

  return new anchor.Program(program.idl as anchor.Idl, program.programId, newProvider)
}
```

Comment: so if I add "signers: [keypair1],", will Anchor use that to sign?

Comment: Yes, you can have mutliple signers in one transaction. Anchor will use all the signers in the signers array + the provider.wallet (since this is being used to pay for the txn). If the signer is not required for the txn then it will throw an error.

Comment: maybe a better question to me is how to override the signers array to assert a failure? It appears to me that the provider.wallet is always passed along, even if I do `signers: []` (which naively looks like there would not be any signers at all). I didn't find a way to remove the default signer and simulate a call from a random wallet.

Comment: @ChristopheVidal if you want your program to be paid by another user I've updated my answer to include this

Comment: thank you, very insightful. I would have thought there was something a little bit more straightforward on how to do this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change feePayer instead of using this:

```
   let tx = await program.methods.initializeProgram().rpc()
```

you can use this:

```
let tx = await program.methods.initializeProgram().transaction();      
tx.feePayer = user.publicKey;
const txID = await connection.sendTransaction(tx,[user , admin ]);
await connection.confirmTransaction(txID);
```